# Can't to talk with other pods using Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

How I understand that I could be able to talk with other pods from a specific pod by sending from within the pod an HTTP request with the fully qualified domain name of the service (FQDN).
The system runs locally with minikube.

The service's YML -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kubia
spec:
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP 
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: kubia
```

The describe of the service -

```
Name:              kubia
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=kubia
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.111.178.111
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.7:8080,172.17.0.8:8080,172.17.0.9:8080
Session Affinity:  ClientIP
Events:            <none>
```

I'm trying to do that with -

```
 kubectl exec -it kubia-gqd5l bash
```

where kubia-gqd5l is the pod.
In the bash I tried to sent a request by -

```
curl http://kubia
```

Where kubia is the name of the service.
and I got error -

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: kubia.

It is important to note that I manage to communicate with the service by -

```
 kubectl exec kubia-gqd5l -- curl -s http://10.111.178.111
```

any idea?

Comment: what type of service is `kubia`? It needs to be NodePort or LoadBalancer for it to be accessed from the outside of your Minikube cluster. Run `kubectl get svc/kubia`

Comment: But I'm trying access to the service from within the cluster, from a pod that is a part of the cluster. I added to the post the YML file of the service. @sulabhchaturvedi

Comment: No, you're not. As, your cluster is Minikube which is deployed with a VM (vm-driver) and you are running commands on your machine. Update your service type to `NodePort` and run, `minikube services kubia  --url` and run the ouput url in your browser.

Comment: I will try this. But, why actually the below command works for me? what is the difference? - `kubectl exec kubia-gqd5l -- curl -s http://10.111.178.111`

Comment: because with that command, you are executing a shell command (curl) in your pod directly

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How trying to send a request to the service from within a pod which leaves inside minikube is considering as from outside of the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes clusters usually have DNS deployed. That allows pod to pod communications *within* the cluster (among other things) by using the name of the corresponding Kubernetes services. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Does your Kubernetes cluster/minikube have DNS running?

Something else to check is the selector in the Service definition - make sure the pod/deployment has the `app: kubia` label as specified in the selector.

Otherwise, and per the doc at the link above, because the lookup of the service is from a pod in the same namespace, it shouldn't be needed to use the namespace along with the service name: (quote) "...Assume a Service named foo in the Kubernetes namespace bar. A Pod running in namespace bar can look up this service by simply doing a DNS query for foo. A Pod running in namespace quux can look up this service by doing a DNS query for foo.bar".

Comment: I added the service's YML file to my post. It seems to me that I'm doing what the docs suggest so I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Seeing 3 endpoints "behind" the service means that the selector in the Service definition is correct. Could you check if DNS pods are actually running and healthy? For example: `kubectl -n kube-system get pods`, look at the READY column of pods with "dns" in the name like "coredns".

Comment: You right :| I see that the dns pods crashed.                                                          

`coredns-5c98db65d4-hsnwx           0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   768        43d
coredns-5c98db65d4-w7jrk           0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   767        43d
`
How can I fix that?

Comment: Aside from the "usual" trobleshooting of CrashLoopBackOff error (get the events, logs...), there are some related SO questions that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+CrashLoopBackOff+coredns

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer [2 Kubernetes pod communicating without knowing the exposed address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57626255/2-kubernetes-pod-communicating-without-knowing-the-exposed-address/57626630#57626630), to target a service it's better to add the namespace with the service.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood exactly what he meant, but I have tried to use - kubia.defualt.svc.cluster.local and it didn't help

Comment: You should be able to use kubia.default:80.. if not could you post a describe of your service?

Comment: I added it to the post @night-gold